# How to update state using Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am using this starter kit https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit and am following some tutorials at the same time, but the style of this codebase is slightly more advanced/different than the tutorials I am watching. I am just a little lost with one thing.

**HomeView.js** - This is just a view that is used in the router, there are higher level components like `Root` elsewhere I don't think I need to share that, if I do let me know, but it's all in the github link provided above.

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { searchListing } from '../../redux/modules/search'

export class HomeView extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount () {
    console.log(this.props)
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <main onClick={this.props.searchListing}>
        <NavBar search={this.props.search} />
        <Hero/>
        <FilterBar/>
        <Listings/>
        <Footer/>
      </main>
    )
  }
}
```

I am using `connect()` and passing in `mapStateToProps` to tell the `HomeView` component about the state. I am also telling it about my `searchListing` function that is an action which returns a type and payload.

```
export const searchListing = (value) => {
    console.log(value)
    return {
        type: SEARCH_LISTINGS,
        payload: value
    }
}
```

Obviously when I call the method inside the `connect()` I am passing in an empty object `searchListing: () => searchListing({})`

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    search: { city: state.search }
  }
}

export default connect((mapStateToProps), { searchListing: () => searchListing({}) })(HomeView)
```

This is where I am stuck, I am trying to take the pattern from the repo, which they just pass `1`, I think anytime that action is created the logic is just add `1` there is no new information passed from the component.

What I am trying to accomplish is input search into a form and from the component pass the users query into the action payload, then the reducer, then update the new state with the query. I hope that is the right idea.

So if in the example the `value` of `1` is hardcoded and passed into the `connect()` method, how can I make it so that I am updating `value` from the component dynamically? Is this even the right thinking?

Comment: I am starting to figure it out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it right. Just modify the `connect` function to pass the action you want to call directly:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
     search: { city: state.search }
});

export default connect((mapStateToProps), {
  searchListing
})(HomeView);
```

Then you may use this action with `this.props.searchListing(stringToSearch)` where `stringToSearch` is a variable containing the input value.

Notice : You don't seem to currently retrieve the user query. You may need to retrieve it first and then pass it to the `searchListing` action.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to call a function method, use `dispatch`.

```
import { searchListing } from '../../redux/modules/search';

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    searchListing: () => {
        dispatch(searchListing());
    }
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomeView);
```

Then, you have made the function a prop, use it with `searchListing`.